# I can't convert Android HPROF to standard HPROF on Lollipop

Tags: android, hprof

My test device version is 5.0.1 (Lollipop).

I get Android heap dump file in Android Studio 1.3.

But I saw error message.

[image: android error message]

So I try to get dump file (example file name: android.hprof) in DDMS.

Then I try to convert Android HPROF to standard HPROF file.

```
hprof-conv android.hprof standard.hprof
```

Then `hprof-conv` return message that is `ERROR: read 40070 of 65559 bytes`

Somebody help me.

Comment: Did you found out the reason of this issue?

Comment: Having the same error : There seems to be a problem in the head dump's content. If I reboot the tablet and take a head dump elsewhere in my application, it works. If I do the manipulation I suspect to be leaking... it fails.

Comment: I got this error when no space available.

Answer (score 0):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/tools/hprof-conv/HprofConv.c#221

```
/*
 * Read some data, adding it to the expanding buffer.
 *
 * This will ensure that the buffer has enough space to hold the new data
 * (plus the previous contents).
 */
static int ebReadData(ExpandBuf* pBuf, FILE* in, size_t count, int eofExpected)
{
    size_t actual;
    assert(count > 0);
    ebEnsureCapacity(pBuf, count);
    actual = fread(pBuf->storage + pBuf->curLen, 1, count, in);
    if (actual != count) {
        if (eofExpected && feof(in) && !ferror(in)) {
            /* return without reporting an error */
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: read %d of %d bytes\n", actual, count);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    pBuf->curLen += count;
    assert(pBuf->curLen <= pBuf->maxLen);
    return 0;
}
```